# How to kill a process started as daemon?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, process

I start a process using `foo &`.

It outputs something like:

> `[1] 16915`

This is the process id, I guess.
How can I store this number into a variable named `MY_PROCESS_ID` (for example)?

Then I can do:

```
kill $MY_PROCESS_ID
```

and my process id will be killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foo &
bg_pid=$!
kill "$bg_pid"
```

You can also use the shell's internal `kill` command with (at least in case of `bash`) the job number:

```
foo &
kill %1
```

But that's probably not easier. May be easier interactively. But with

```
kill %+
```

or

```
kill %
```

you always get the last one. You can even identify the job to be killed by parts of the command line. See `man bash`; search for the block `JOB CONTROL`.

Comment: As single `%` will refer to the last job started.

Answer (score 1):

The `$!` variable is the PID if the last process started in the background. You would do:

```
foo &
my_process_id=$!

: other stuff ...

kill "$my_process_id"
```